# Мобильная версия карточки товара woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

В общем проблема такова, как начать с новой строки название товара, что его не корежело в мобильной версии. На компе все в порядке.
http://www.milanew.com/product/dzhemper-ld-642/
[image: скрин с мобильного]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В style.css вашей темы добавьте

```
.woocommerce div.product .product_title {
    clear: both;
}
```